# Test the equality of some elements and/or columns in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices:

$X$ =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

$Y$ =

```
 1    10    11
 4    12    13
 7    14    15
```

I know that if I want to find the index of a specific element in $X$ or $Y$, I can use the function ''find''. For example: $index_3 = find(X==3)$.

1) My first question is how can i find (or test) if $X$ contains some elements that are also present in $Y$? can I use the function ''find''? if yes so how?

2) The second question is related to the first. Now I want to find (or test) if some columns in $X$ are also present in $Y$. For example, how can I demonstrate in matlab that the column $[1;2;3]$ in $X$ is also present in $Y$?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both of these with [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). For the first one, it's simply:

```
locsX = ismember(X, Y);
```

For your test matrices this gives you:

```
locsX =

   1   0   0
   1   0   0
   1   0   0
```

For another example:

```
X =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

Z =

    1    7   13
    3    9   15
    5   11   17

>> ismember(X, Z)
ans =

   1   0   1
   0   1   0
   1   0   1
```

For the second part of your question, `ismember` has an optional flag to compare **rows**:

```
rowsX = ismember(X, Y, 'rows');
```

so to get the columns, just take the transpose of both matrices:

```
rowsX = ismember(X.', Y.', 'rows')

rowsX =

   1
   0
   0
```

Comment: That answer isn't enough for me, but it can give insights to get more solutions from other people. Thank you very much for your time and help. Cheers

Comment: @Christina Well, if you clarify how it doesn't work for you, perhaps we can improve on the solution.