# Automatic test for the equality of columns between two matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have two matrices:

```
X =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9

`Y` =

     1    10    11
     4    12    13
     7    14    15
```

I know that if I want to find the index of a specific element in `X` or `Y`, I can use the function `find`. For example: 
`index_3 = find(X==3)`

What I want is to find or search in a very automatic way if a column in `X` is also present in `Y`. In other terms, I want a function which can tell me if a column in `X` is equal to a column in `Y`. In fact to to try this, one can use the function `ismember` which indeed has an optional flag to compare rows:

```
rowsX = ismember(X, Y, 'rows');
```

So a simple way to get columns is just by taking the transpose of both matrices:

```
rowsX = ismember(X.', Y.', 'rows')
rowsX =

   1
   0
   0
```

But how can I do that in other manner?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: why do you say that `ismember(X.', Y.', 'rows')` is not automatic? o.O

Comment: Sorry it is automatic, but I want another function that can directly give me ''1'' if a column in X is also present in Y, or ''0'' if it is not

Comment: if you mean that you want to check whether a column in X exists in Y, then you can do `if ( any( ismember(X.', Y.', 'rows') ) )..`. `any( ismember(X.', Y.', 'rows') )` will return you your "0" or "1".

Comment: Ok thank you that helps. However I also tried this: `if(find(ismember(X.', Y.', 'rows')) == 1)`. That is, if a 1 is present, this means that one or more columns between `X` and `Y` are equal. What do you think?

Comment: `find(...)` works in this case because in your example only 1 column in X is found in Y: `[1 0 0] = ismember(...)`. So when you do `find([1 0 0]) == 1` you will get a single output. But if you have more than 1 column in X that exists in Y then you will get back an `vector` again with `find(..) == 1`. Example: `find([1 0 1]) == 1` will give you `[1 3]`.

Comment: Exactly! thank you for the remark.

Comment: @Christina is it not clear why you want an alternative to `ismember(X.', Y.', 'rows')`, can you elaborate on that? What about `ismember` is not satisfactory?

Comment: @Dan thanks for your question. In fact i just wanted to know if there is another function which can directly give either 1 or 0. But since any(ismember(..)) can give this, so it is ok for me now.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903000/test-the-equality-of-some-elements-and-or-columns-in-matlab. I'm still not sure what you want that's different from the `ismember` solution. Is it possible that you simply want `colsX = rowsX.'`? Perhaps I named my variable poorly. :)

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late reply I had some problems with my laptop.. In fact your answer was perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
rowsX = any(all(bsxfun(@eq, X, permute(Y, [1 3 2])), 1), 3);
```

With

```
X = [ 1     2     3
      4     5     6
      7     8     9 ];
Y = [ 1    10    11
      4    12    13
      7    14    15 ];
```

this gives

```
rowsX =
     1     0     0
```

**How it works**

`permute` "turns `Y` 90 degrees" along a vertical axis, so columns of `Y` are kept aligned with columns of `X`,  but rows of `Y` are moved to the third dimension. Testing for equality with `bsxfun` and applying `all(...,1)` gives a matrix that tells which columns of `X` equal which columns of `Y`. Then `any(...,3)` produces the desired result: `true` if a column of `X` equals any column of `Y`.